# Xcode 7.3 Unit Tests .xcdatamodel "cdtool cannot compile"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I have experiencing really weird build error. It all builds well for a normal target but since an update to Xcode 7.3 the Tests target started throwing error

"cdtool cannot compile" on one of my model versions "CoreData 9.xcdatamodel"

during the build. The project builds and runs perfectly for a normal, non test target.

I checked in on different Macs and even on an external CI provider (bitrise.io) - the issues exists everywhere.

Comment: If this is a bug then you should log it with Apple at: https://bugreport.apple.com . It's more likely to be fixed if you report it.

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat but I am fully aware of Apple bug reporting tool. I was hoping to get an answer and someone's solution here as someone might be experiencing a similar issue as there is few questions and solutions around "cdtool cannot compile" but none of them solve my case.